# Hydrated_BLoC - states with different attributes - access stored state type

Tags: flutter, dart, caching, bloc

I want to save my Cubit so that I can receive the state of it after I reopen my app.

I use different states with different attributes, shown in the following:

```
abstract class State {}

class InitState extends State {}

class BuildingState extends State {
  final List<A> aList;
  final List<B> bList;

  BuildingState({
    required this.aList,
    required this.bList,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {'aList': aList, 'bList': bList};
  }

  factory BuildingState.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return BuildingState(
      aList: map['aList'] as List<A>,
      bList: map['bList'] as List<B>,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory BuildingState.fromJson(String source) =>
      BuildingState.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}

class RunningState extends State {
  final List<C> cModel;

  RunningState({required this.cModel});

Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {'cList': cList};
  }

  factory RunningState.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return RunningState(cList: map['cList'] as List<C>);
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory RunningState.fromJson(String source) =>
      RunningState.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

The three different states have different attributes.

Currently I have the following Cubit:

```
class Cubit extends Cubit<State> with HydratedMixin {
  Cubit() : super(InitState());

  ...

  @override
  State? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (state is BuildingState) {               // -> This state is the current cubit state and not the state from the storage
      return BuildingState.fromMap(json);
    } else if (state is RunningState) {
      return RunningState.fromMap(json);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(State state) {
    if (state is BuildingState) { 
      return state.toMap();
    } else if (state is RunningState) {
      return state.toMap();
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

My problem is that I used the wrong state in the fromJson method.

**My question** is how I can access the state type from the storage in my fromJson method and then how I can perform the correct (de)serialization. *(as mentioned [here](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2392#issuecomment-888354916))*

**Edit:**
For now I solved the problem by using JSON serialization/deserialization to save and retrieve the state of my Cubit class.
If there is a better way of doing it, please let me know.

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
  List aList = a.map((aItem) => aItem.toJson()).toList();
  debugPrint(aList.first['format']);
  return {
    'state': 'buildingState',
    'a': a.map((aItem) => aItem.toJson()).toList(),
  };
}

State? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    String state = json['state'];
    if (state == 'buildingState') {

    ...

    } else if (state == 'runningState') {
      return RunningState.fromMap(json);
    } else if (state == 'initState') {
      return InitState();
    } else {
      debugPrint('Error from a_cubit - fromJson');

      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: @DNS I solved the problem by using JSON serialization/deserialization to save and retrieve the state of my Cubit class, as mentioned in the edit.

```Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    List aList =
        a.map((aItem) => aItem.toJson()).toList();
    debugPrint(aList.first['format']);
    return {
      'state': 'a',
      'a': a.map((aItem) => aItem.toJson()).toList(),
    };
  }```